# Var not visible to be passed into an UrlAction

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've seen this working in other examples but don't know why I cannot pass the var value into the urlAction:

```
function onCommandInfoClick(e, args) {
    var _reservNo = args.row.data[0];

    // This works as expected.
    alert( _reservNo);

    // The _reservNo var is not visible inside the @UrlAction 
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetContract", "Reservation", new { reservNo = ???? })'

    window.location.href = url;
}
```

I've solved the problem in the following way, but not sure it is the right solution

```
function onCommandInfoClick(e, args) {
    var _reservNo = args.row.data[0];
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetContract", "Reservation", new { reservNo = "selection"})'
    window.location.href = url.replace("selection", _reservNo);
```

Comment: String concatenation should work just as well: `var url = '@Url.Action("GetContract", "Reservation", new { reservNo = ' + _reservNo + ' })'`

Comment: @ArrayKnight Thanks for the suggestion, but I had tried like that also, and it gives compile error (VS 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Well the other option is to generated the URL's in the server side, where you should have your reserveNo variable available, and then return the URL's in your json. Should be easier to maintain because if you rewrite the route you wont have to do any changes in your client side code.

Comment: This is interesting.But it will require using Ajax and a round trip to the server right? The way it is now, it sends the request to the server only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following -

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetContract", "Reservation", new { reservNo = ' + _reservNo + '})'
```